# Privacy threat of home based employee using wireless laptop

Tags: privacy, wifi

My wife works for a large bank and they are sending her a new Wi-Fi laptop.

Quite a while ago, the bank stopped paying for internet service, so we have to. Now they want to connect to our private wireless network that our family use.

She has been working through LAN cables connected to a bank router prior to this, so the only difference is the wireless aspect.

I am quite concerned by the privacy aspect of this. It really gets me fired up. What should I be concerned about for the non-business users and what can I do other than pay another $100+ for internet service?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to the *Information Security* community, part of the Stack Exchange family of sites. Can you clarify what you mean by `Now they want to connect to our private wireless network that the family uses.`?

Comment: I'm not sure what are you asking exactly but if she connects directly to the corporate network, VPN should be used (best if provided by the company).

Comment: This whole scenario hinges on the detail "they want to connect to our private wireless network", which you do not define. Without understanding what you mean by this, we are left guessing.

Answer (score 2):

From your description it looks like your wife has some VPN client software installed on her laptop.
In case my assumption is correct, your wife uses a VPN software installed on her laptop, the transmission of data is being encrypted on her laptop before the data is sent. The same in the opposite direction - all data from the bank is encrypted and is being decrypted after reaching your wife's laptop.

In such case there is nothing to worry about for as long as the bank keeps their encryption software well maintained, your wife uses the VPN software to connect to the bank and keeps the internet security software up to date (in case she uses the laptop for some other tasks (like for example browsing the Internet).

When the VPN is in use, all data transfer is encrypted. VPN is a way of transferring secure data over the insecure medium (wired networks, wireless networks, mobile phone networks, public airport networks, any networks). 
That's all assuming your wife is using VPN, it is up to you to find out.
I hope this helps.